# Submit form works randomly

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a table form, and get the *names* and variables with cycles. The thing is, when submit is pressed sometimes it works, sometimes doesn't, I don't know why.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$sector = limpiarDatos($_POST['sector']);
$numeroPedido = limpiarDatos($_POST['numeroPedido']);
$fechaSolicitud = limpiarDatos($_POST['fechaSolicitud']);
for ( $x = 1; $x < 24; $x++ ) {
    $fechaRequerida[$x] = limpiarDatos($_POST['fechaRequerida'.$x]);
    $codigo[$x] = limpiarDatos($_POST['codigo'.$x]);
    $descripcion[$x] = limpiarDatos($_POST['descripcion'.$x]);
    $cantidad[$x] = limpiarDatos($_POST['cantidad'.$x]);
    $observacion[$x] = limpiarDatos($_POST['observacion'.$x]);

    if (!empty($descripcion[$x])) {
        $statement = $conexion->prepare(
            '
INSERT INTO pedidos 
( id
, numero_pedido
, sector
, fecha_solicitud
, fecha_requerida
, codigo
, descripcion
, cantidad
, observacion
) VALUES 
( NULL
, :numeroPedido
, :sector
, :fechaSolicitud
, :fechaRequerida'.$x.'
, :codigo'.$x.'
, :descripcion'.$x.'
, :cantidad'.$x.'
, :observacion'.$x.'
)
'
        );

        $statement->execute(array(
        ':numeroPedido' => $numeroPedido,
        ':sector' => $sector,
        ':fechaSolicitud' => $fechaSolicitud,
        ':fechaRequerida'.$x => $fechaRequerida[$x],
        ':codigo'.$x => $codigo[$x],
        ':descripcion'.$x => $descripcion[$x],
        ':cantidad'.$x => $cantidad[$x],
        ':observacion'.$x => $observacion[$x],
        ));
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

I checked that the method is POST, syntax of the variables is correct, even add echo "string" into if statement when submitted, and it works, but no data is saved to the db (but sometimes if). HELP please!

Comment: So there is 23 descriptions and if any one of them empty you insert nothing ?

Comment: *else break*, inserted only if there are no empty fields

Comment: Okay, i just had a guess, that you really want to use `continue;` not `break;`

Comment: duh.. I trying to send varchar in a field when this is int type; my bad. The code is ok!